# A Geometry Problem with parallel lines in a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

In trapezoid $ABCD$ with bases $AB$ and $CD$, $AB = 14$ and $CD = 6$. Points $E$ and $F$ belong to $AB$, such that $AD || CE$ and $BC || DF$. Segments $DF$ and $CE$ intersect at $G$ and $AG$ intersects $BC$ at $H$. Compute $\frac{S_{\triangle{CGH}}}{S_{ABCD}}$...($S_{XYZ}$ $\text{means area of}$ $XYZ$).

My Attempt:

[DGC]=9[GEF]

[DAF]=16[GEF]

[CGFB]=15[GEF]

[ABCD]=40[GEF]

But after this I couldn't go any further... PLEASE HELP...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints :**

- Show that $\triangle DAG \sim \triangle CGH$ with similarity ratio $4/3$.
- Relate the areas of $\triangle DAG$ and $\triangle DAF$ using $S_\triangle = $ base $\times$ height $/2$.

Let perpendicular from $A$ to line $DF$ has length $h$. Then

$$\frac{S_{\triangle DAG}}{S_{\triangle DAG}}=\frac{\tfrac{1}{2}DG \times h}{\tfrac{1}{2}DF \times h} = \frac{DG}{DF} \\$$

Finally, use your findings to compute $S_{\triangle CGH}$ in terms of $S_{ABCD}$.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov See the edit.

Comment: How do I show similarity ratio of 4/3 ??

Comment: Note ratio $=AG/GH=AF/FB$ since $GF \parallel HB$

Comment: By BPT theorem...I got it...Thanks...